# postgresql how to use boolean in where statement

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I'm a really bad in sql , my query is

```
 select * from car_wash where
           (select ST_Within((select car_wash.lon_lat from car_wash),(select ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(65.3 323.2)'),20)))) = true
        AND car_wash.was_deleted=false;
```

But i know that it isn't correct because nested query can return more than 1 column, how to modify this query to use where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from car_wash cw
where
   ST_Within (
       cw.lon_lat,
       ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(65.3 323.2)'),20)
   )
   AND
   not car_wash.was_deleted
```

Comment: Thank you, but it should be
select *
from car_wash cw
where
   ST_Within (
       cw.lon_lat,
       ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(65.3 323.2)'),20)
   )=true
   AND
   not cw.was_deleted

Can you say,how to use where statement if my query can return many columns

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак The where clause is not dependent on the number of returned columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use postgresql, but maybe something like this works:

```
select * from car_wash 
where EXISTS (select ST_Within((select car_wash.lon_lat from car_wash),
                 (select ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(65.3 323.2)'),20))) within 
              WHERE within = true)
AND car_wash.was_deleted=false;
```

If it doesn't work, I have a variant, so tell me when.

Comment: Hello, can you help me with following question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450016/postgresql-postgis-if-point-inside-circle