# postgresql postgis If point inside circle

Tags: postgresql, distance, postgis

I'm using postgresql as db , i have the table named car_wash  with field "point geometry"(use postgis) so in application I'm getting lon lat from user using GOOGLE API, next step I need to create circle around user and check if car_wash inside this circle I use

```
  select *
 from car_wash cw
where
ST_DWithin (
   cw.lon_lat,
   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.21 22.54)')
)=false
AND
not cw.was_deleted
```

Is it corect way? IF you need my srid is 0 according to this query

```
 Select Find_SRID('public',  'car_wash',  'lon_lat')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SRID of the ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.21 22.54)') must be same as the SRID of cw.lon_lat. Suppose SRID of cw.lon_lat is 4326 you can set the other attribute srib by using  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.21 22.54)',4326).
Secondly, ST_DWithin needs buffer distance as 3rd parameter. So suppose if you want to check if point is within 100 meter buffer it should be like

```
ST_DWithin (
   cw.lon_lat,
   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.21 22.54)', 3857), 100
)
```

Buffer value is according to the srid unit. in case of 3857 its meter. You need to convert cw.lon_lat and POINT(54.21 22.54) to the same SRID in order to make this work, using st_setSRID e.g.

Comment: Thank for response , can i ask one more question, for get lonLat from user i use hybernete , i don't get srid so all SRIDs is 0, is ST_DWithin will get meters as param or radians?

Comment: you must know the srid of parameter to work st_dwithin. you may have idea from where lon_lat is comming and from there you can check what srid they are using. in case of google most probably it is 4326. after that set the srid of both param same . like  ST_DWithin (
   st_setSRID(cw.lon_lat, 4326),
   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(54.21 22.54)', 4326), 100
).

Comment: in case of 4326 its unit is degree, in case of 3857 its meter. you can seach about the unit of  any srid

Comment: -1 because your code sets 3857 to a point in lat-long. You need to create the point in 4326 then project it using st_transform to 3857. Your 1st comment suggest a buffer of 100 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

While using `ST_DWithin` function, your third parameter must be distance.
You can also define srid in `ST_GeomFromText`

there are two simple example so you can see difference:

```
select ST_DWithin(
st_geomfromtext('POINT(54.51 22.54)',4326),
st_geomfromtext('POINT(54.21 22.54)',4326),0.5
)
result is true

select ST_DWithin(
st_geomfromtext('POINT(54.51 22.54)',4326),
st_geomfromtext('POINT(54.21 22.54)',4326),0.1
)
result is false
```

Source:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: Thanks, but if srid is zero for both points third param of ST_DWithin is distance on meters or radians?

Comment: st_geomfromtext always return geometry. it means distence is meters. So you must use st_geogfromtext (geography )for real distence. There is a exeample : select st_distance (st_geogfromtext('POINT(54.11 22.54)'),st_geogfromtext('POINT(54.21 22.54)')) result 10286.66378146 meter

Comment: [link](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) ST_DWithin: For geometry units are in those of spatial reference(so it change about srid) and For geography units are in meters . i think geography better solution for u

Answer (score 1):

First - i assume that lat_long is georaphy type column. If it is geometry type column you will have to modify my examples to some other EPSG (propably 3857 metric EPSG for whole world). It is very important because st_dwithin check in meters for geopraphy type , and in map units for geometry (and for EPSG 4326 unit is degree not meter)

Insert your data like this

```
insert into car_wash values (1,'aaa',st_setsrid(st_makepoint(54.51, 22.54),4326))
```

I explain why use st_setsrid, st_makepoint, and what the hell is 4326.
 - 4326 is EPSG 4326 - it is most known coordinate reference system (where you have lat and long in degrees).

- st_makepoint - will create geography point from your lat and long coordinates. It will looks like bytes, but dont worry, if you will need lat and long for some reasons you can get them with st_x() and st_y() or st_astext() functions. Best thing of have geoms or geogs (in this case) is that you can use gist index. Very powerful tool that speed up your geo queries.
- st_setsrid - st_makepoint will create point but with srid=0. You have to tell POSTGIS in what EPSG it should read your data. For example if you tell him to read it with 4326 it will be in correct places on google world map, but if you say for example 3857 it will be in completly diffrent place, as 3857 is metric system not degree so it will be around 50 and 50 meters from left down corner (or maybe left up, dont remember)

Create index on geog

```
create index on car_wash using gist (geog);
```

We have table, we have data in it and index on it. Now we want to check if your point is close to any of your car washes.

```
select *
  from car_wash cw
 where ST_DWithin (cw.geog,ST_GeogFromtext('SRID=4326;POINT(54.21 22.54)'),1000)
  AND cw.was_deleted=false
```

In ST_DWithin third parameters is distance in meters (georpahy) or map units (geometry). So in this case it will show you all car washes that are up to 1000 meters from your user location and are not deleted.